# How to crop image after capture image by camera in cordova, same as whatsapp crop functionality

Tags: image, cordova, crop

In my app I am using image capture functionality by camera in profile picture section but in android it returns rectangular size image and after resizing the image gets distorted.

To avoid Image distortion I need *square size croped image*, same as functionality provided by whatsapp.

Is there any plugin to get square size image or crop image like square?

Comment: lol - from sumit kothari

Comment: btw check [cordova-imageResizer](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imageResizer) and [cordova-camera-android-crop-available](https://github.com/zhushunqing/cordova-camera-android-crop-available)

Comment: I have already checked both but not working for android.